# What are ambient declarations

Tags: typescript

I've been seeing a lot using articles mentioning `ambient declarations`. For example [this article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/). What are they? Can somebody provide an example? Is an ambient declaration a declaration of a type created outside existing typescript files but used in these files? Are all declarations **ambient**?

As I understand `ambient declarations` don't produce any javascript code and are defined using `declare` keyword. Is this the only case of ambient declarations or there are others?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, ambient declarations let you tell the compiler about existing variable/functions/etc.

For example let's say that in your web page you're using a library that adds a global variable, let's say that it's name is `ON_READY` and it is a reference to a function.
You need to assign a function to it so you'll do something like:

```
ON_READY = () => {
    console.log("ready!");
    ...
};
```

The compiler will complain that:

> Cannot find name 'ON_READY'

So you use an ambient declaration to inform the compiler that this variable exists and what it's type is:

```
declare var ON_READY: () => void;
```

Now it won't complain about not finding it.

---

#### Edit

When using the `declare` keyword it is always ambient, just like it says in the article you linked to:

> **The declare keyword is used for ambient declarations** where you want to
>   define a variable that may not have originated from a TypeScript file

Non-ambient declarations are just normal variable/function declarations:

```
let x: number;
const y = "string";
var a = () => { console.log("here"); }
```

Comment: thanks. are all declarations ambient? what is an example of not an ambient declaration?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: thanks, so does `ambient` really mean `outside` in `ambient declarations`?

Comment: I wouldn't use "outside", it's more like "trust me, it exists"

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/180 and https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/343

Comment: @NitzanTomer, thanks, one more question, what are the other ways to tell that something "trust me, it exists", instead of using `declare` word

Comment: I guess that the only other thing I can think that matches that description is when existing objects are being extended (more on that in the [Global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) part of the docs)

Comment: So if I have a typescript project, and all 3rd party libs I referenced have a typescript definition (index.d.ts), I don't need `declare` anywhere in my project right?

Comment: @BruceSun That's correct, in most cases (if you have types for all libs) you don't need to `declare` yourself

Comment: I guess we are aware of the type erasure concept in typescript, meaning, all that is declared using the ‘declare’ keyword in the typescript file will be erased and will not be included in the compiled javascript file. The importance of the things declared in typescript using the ‘declare’ keyword is that they help in the type checking feature of typescript during design and compile time. After that, they will not be included in the final javascript file.

Comment: @SimbaMeek **ALL** types information is removed by the compiler, as javascript doesn't have the notion of types. So that has nothing to do with the `declare` keyword.

Comment: You're right, @NitzanTomer - that javascript has no notion of types.

Answer (score 2):

*This came from a TypeScript handbook contributor (attribution below).*

### "module"

---

A module is a file with a top level `import` or `export`, as defined by the ES6 spec, previously referred to as "external module"

### "script"

---

A script is a file that is not a "module".

We should be using this instead of "global", as "global" is relative to the import; whereas "script" is about the content of the file, not how it is used. This is also consistent with the ES6 terminology.

### "ambient"

---

Anything that does not have an implementation, e.g.:

- ambient variable declaration => `declare var $: any`
- ambient class declaration => `declare class C { foo(); }`, etc..

A module can be ambient as well; so

- "ambient module" is a .d.ts file with a top level `import` or `export`.
- "ambient module declaration" is something of the form `declare module "foo" { ... }`

#### Attribution:

---

[This was written by mhegazy](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/180#issuecomment-195452691) with minor grammar/spelling/capitalization fixes by me.

I found it through [a comment made by @Paleo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915902/what-are-ambient-declarations#comment69045407_40916055) in a different answer within this post. I thought it was so good it was worth sharing as its own answer.