# WebStorm TypeScript definitions don't work

Tags: typescript, three.js, webstorm

I am writing three.js code and enabled TypeScript definitions in settings. But there is no effect. I downloaded it, checked the tick but nothing happened. All three.js code is underlined and WebStorm writes there is no import. Full log:

`Missing import statement less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Checks that all modules are referenced through import statements.
Suggests inserting the import statement.
When using libraries that define their own global symbols outside their visible JavaScript code (e.g. describe() in Mocha), it is recommended that you add the corresponding TypeScript type definition file as a JavaScript library in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries.`

How can I fix it and code normally, cause now it's impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably loading three.js with a regular `<script>` tag. I believe that the declarations you enabled are not "ambient", they describe what is exported by the it's commonjs module thus it doesn't consider your setup that has three.js globally available.

You might be able to make these definitions to be used by WebStorm as [ambient declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915902/what-is-ambient-declarations) somehow but the intended way of working with this is by [importing three.js via modules](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Import-via-modules).

Comment: I use not only `script` tag, but TypeScript definitions. A few months ago it worked but now it doesn't. I do all the same. P.S. Probably, now I need add import comment, but I don't remember, how.

Comment: If you're writing code with TypeScript the "import comment" you refer to could be a [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html). Otherwise I have no idea how you made it work before, sorry :(