# Typescript Reference to external Module in Namespace

Tags: typescript, momentjs, typescript-typings

I'm trying to refer to an external module '**moment**' in my namespace '**company.controllers**'

```
namespace company.controllers {    
    import { moment } from 'moment';

    'use strict'

    export class WidgetAdminDailyStatisticController extends Controller<company.data.AdminDailyStatisticViewModel> {
        customRepository: company.data.CustomRepository;
        searchDate: Date;

        static $inject: Array<string> = [
            'CustomRepository'
        ];
        constructor(
            customRepository: company.data.CustomRepository
        ) {
            super();

            this.customRepository = customRepository;
        }

        initialize(): void {
            this.searchDate = new Date();

            //let a: moment = new moment();


        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting "**Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference to a module**"

How do I import moment and use in my typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You can import it outside the namespace:

```
import { moment } from 'moment';

namespace company.controllers {
    // ...
}
```

... but you can't import a module in non-module scripts. If your namespace is not in a module, it's not possible. The solution is to use *moment* as a global variable, and to find (or write) another definition file for that global variable.

Comment: When I moved it outside the namespace, it works. BUT i'm getting errors on 'Controller<company.data.AdminDailyStatisticViewModel>'. 
1. Curly line under 'Controller'. Error message: "Cannot find name Controller"
2. Curly line under 'company.data'. Error message: "Namespace 'company' has no exported member data".

Both above works fine before.

Comment: Indeed. You can't import a module in non-module scripts. If the namespace is not in a module, it's not possible. The solution is to use _moment_ as a global variable.

Comment: I found a way to do it. By comment out "export = moment" in the type definition file.

Comment: Sorry, I can't validate your edition because it is a hack specific to _moment_. What you need is the [_ambient_ type definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915902/what-are-ambient-declarations) for _moment_. I don't know if it exists for `moment`. By removing the line `export = moment` in the definition file, you make the definition file _ambient_. But this hacks depends on the way the definition file has been written, and it is not a general solution for _"referencing an external module from a namespace"_. However, your solution works for you, that's the most important thing. :)

Comment: My bad. The correct term is not _ambient_ but _global_.